# Generic type and ProtoBuf

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm currently testing protobuf(with WCF, but not the concern) to serialize our whole model.

I did encountered an issue, I've one generic class, to make it simple let say:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Container<T>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public T Object { get; }

    public Container(T containedObject)
    {
        Object = containedObject;
    }
}
```

But when I try to serialize/deserialize it(with an int), I get this message

> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException : Type
>   'XXXX.Container`1[System.Int32]' cannot be serialized.
>   Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and
>   marking all of its members you want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider
>   marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the
>   Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

Comment: What version of protobuf-net are you using?

Comment: The 2.3.0.0, last one available on nuget I think

Comment: Have you tried adding data contract notation to try to make WCF not freak out?

Comment: You mean using [DataContract] instead of [ProtoContract]  The thing is that there is some places where I've no choice(due to IsReference =true)

Comment: @MarcGravell It works if I use DataContract instead of ProtoContract, not sure why?

Comment: you can *use both* :) protobuf-net will prefer the `[ProtoContract]` / `[ProtoMember]` version - allowing you fine-grained control, but the `[DataContract]` stuff will make WCF happy

Comment: Can you put your answers into an answer so i can accept it ?

Comment: @MarcGravell Also, in my case, you would recommend to always use `[DataContract, ProtoContract]`in all my classes?